# Connecting to Cassandra in Flask and multithreaded wsgi application

Tags: python, database, flask, cassandra, wsgi

I am trying to connect to cassandra database in flask app running using multithreaded wsgi gateway. I am trying to connect using following code:

```
def connect_to_cassandra():
    auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=config['username'], password=config['password'])
    cluster = Cluster(contact_points=config['contact_points'], port=config['port'], auth_provider=auth_provider)
    load_balancing_policy = TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(DC))
    cluster.load_balancing_policy = load_balancing_policy
    session = cluster.connect(config['keyspace'])
    return session
```

I am establishing connection only once at the start of application. Whenever I am trying to use this session object for execute statement the code gets stuck on the statment : session.execute() and timesout.
When checked on the cassandra db server, there was no connection being setup after running the application.

This issue is not comming when I am running my flask application without wsgi. Everything is working fine in non wsgi application.

Is there some issue with wsgi and cassandra db connections. Please help me with the solution to it as I have tried all the methods available.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. For guidance, see stackoverflow.com/tour and stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not well-versed in Cassandra, I believe this documentation could be helpful: https://flask-cqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Additionally, you might find cqlalchemy useful for your purposes.